# Crystal Reports 13 bobj is undefined JavaScript Error after installed visual Studio 2015 community edition

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2015

In Visual studio 2010 with Crystal Report 13 my project worked fine.

**After I installed Visual studio 2015 community edition** for my personal use. When i **opened my project and run in Visual studio 2010** it throws "JavaScript runtime error: ‘bobj’ is undefined".

[image]
[image]
 I surfed some website

http://www.mahadera.com/error-0x800a1391-javascript-runtime-error-bobj-is-undefined/
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Crystal-Reports-13-Visual-Studio-2010-Issue-with-IIS---bobj-is-undefined-JavaScript-Error-and-Crystal-Report-Viewer-not-displaying.aspx

and I reinstalled and copied aspnet_client folder and paste into project. Eventhough problem not yet solved. I guess the error because i installed VS2015 community edition.

Please help me and im clueless.

Comment: In VS 2010 it worked for me, too. In VS 2013 no way to make it work, VS 2015 is the same.. To test reports I have to use it in the IDE or just publish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We figured out the root cause of the problem. When you installed VS2015, it installed .NET framework 4.6, which is causing the dreaded "bobj not defined" error. Unfortunately, .NET 4.6 wiped out (or overwrote) earlier version of .NET - whatever comes with VS2010 in your case or VS2013 in my case. You can uninstall .NET 4.6 and then "repair" VS2013, which reinstalled .NET 4.5.1 and the problem went away. Unfortunately, repairing VS2015 puts .NET 4.6 right back and the problem reappears.

So the bottom line, you can either have VS2015 - or earlier version of Visual Studio without bobj error; but not both

Don't thank me - thank Steve :)

Answer (score 2):

1) First of all go to your root directory path in my case it is:    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319

here you will find a folder named "crystalreportviewers13". Copy it paste to the location of your solution.

2)In the head section of the page paste the following javascript refrence:

make sure the src is pointing to your local folder.

after that run your page.

I have the same problem, and this works good for me in VS2015.

Comment: "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319"  was not give me the expected results.                                                              But in my case I copy my "aspnet_client" folder which was in "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\" to my project folder. Thats the only change that I was done. I'm not even map any Javascript reference as mention in above answer. Now my crystal report load fine in VS2015.             Hope some can get help from this.

Comment: this is the src i used that solved my issue...src="aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js"> put this in you java script tag in the head (gigidty) section

Answer (score 1):

Copy:

`Solution_Directory\aspnet_client\system_web\4_5_27\crystalreportviewers13`

To:

`Solution_Directory\aspnet_client\system_web\4_6_81\crystalreportviewers13`

Comment: If you use F12 in Chrome you will see error like this:
GET http://localhost:44320/aspnet_client/system_web/4_6_81/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/images/style.css 

4_6_81 is the missing Dot.Net 4.6 directory

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you could edit that information into the answer, it would be clearer.

Comment: For me, the working solution is to copy `crystalreportviewers13` into working root directory of project.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue but now everything work right.

1. Uninstall framework 4.6.
   After uninstalling 4.6, I found VS didn't work.  Removing .NET 4.6 uninstalled all of .NET 4.x.
2. So I had to reinstall 4.0-4.5.x.  This was accomplished through Windows Update. I then did a reboot and tried to run a website through VS and found that CR worked correctly.

I hope this will helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is finally fixed in SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio - Service Pack 16

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/SAP+Crystal+Reports%2C+developer+version+for+Microsoft+Visual+Studio+-+Service+Pack+16+-+Fixed+Issues

```
Incident 878969    Framework 4.6 causes CR for VS to create a unique folder path to the Crystalreportsviewer13 folder in IIS and IISExpress
```

More info in the following SAP thread:

https://scn.sap.com/thread/3824701